# sql work out growth in query

Tags: sql

I'm trying to work out the percentage of growth between 2 years but it is returning growth as 0.

```
SELECT my.finmonth,
   my.trnyear,
   my.drawofficenum,
   my1.ytdty,
   ly1.ytdly,
   CASE
     WHEN my1.ytdty <> 0 THEN ( my1.ytdty - ly1.ytdly ) / ly1.ytdly * 100
     ELSE 0
   END AS Growth2012
FROM   salestymonth my
   LEFT JOIN salestyytd my1
          ON my.finmonth = my1.finmonth
             AND my.trnyear = my1.trnyear
             AND my.drawofficenum = my1.drawofficenum
   LEFT JOIN saleslyytd ly1
          ON my.finmonth = ly1.finmonth
             AND my.trnyear = ly1.trnyear
             AND my.drawofficenum = ly1.drawofficenum
WHERE  my.finmonth = '1'
ORDER  BY ytdty DESC
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data with sample results that you expect? It's easier for us to help you if you include the data. Also, what RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try 1.00*(my1.YTDTY - ly1.YTDLY) / ly1.YTDLY. If your column types are integers, you won't get non-integer results from dividing unless you force the numerator to be a decimal or float.

Comment: What you say is true for SQL Server but isn't for some other SQL product (MySQL, for instance).

Comment: Also, your `1.00` should probably be `100.0`.